# How do I prevent a pagebreak in `align` before an `intertext`?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, line-breaking, page-breaking

Usually, one can prevent a page break at a line break in an `align`-environment using `\\*`. When the line break in question comes before an `\intertext`, however, there seems to be no effect, as illustrated by the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\usepackage[paperheight=10cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align*}
    a &= b\\*
\intertext{Some text}
    a &= b\\*
\intertext{Some text}
    a &= b
\end{align*}
Some text
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered result of previous code]

I also tried playing around with `\predisplaypenalty` and and `\postdisplaypenalty`, which seem to affect also the penalties for breaking before/after an `\intertext` (for instance, `\postdisplaypenalty=10000` seems to do what I intended here), but I am not sure if that's the way to go and where precisely to alter the penalties.

So, how should I prevent page breaks around `\intertext`s?

Answer (score 2):

The spacing isn't right (more like `\shortintertext`), but it achieves the effect.  Note that without `\allowdisplaybreaks`, `\\*` has the same effect as `\\`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\usepackage[paperheight=10cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{flalign*}
&&    a &= b &&\\*
\text{\rlap{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{Some text}}}\\
&&    a &= b \\*
\text{\rlap{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{Some text}}}\\
&&    a &= b
\end{flalign*}
Some text
\end{document}
```